# gsub - how to be efficient leet generator

Tags: ruby, regex

for fun I am creating in ruby a simple leet (1337) generator

so i am doing something like this, which works but doesn't look very efficient, i am sure it can be accomplished with one line only...

```
    def leet
       words = words.gsub(/a/, '4')
       words = words.gsub(/e/, '3')
       words = words.gsub(/i/, '1')
       words = words.gsub(/o/, '0')
       words = words.gsub(/s/, '5')
       words = words.gsub(/t/, '7')
       puts words
    end
```

Can you give me a help here? :) thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def leet(word)
  puts word.gsub(/[aeiost]/,'a'=>'4','e'=>'3','i'=>'1','o'=>'0','s'=>'5','t'=>'7')
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def leet s
  s.tr 'aeiost', '431057'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

A more general version of megas's:

```
class Leet
    @@map = {
        'a' => '4',
        'e' => '3',
        'i' => '1',
        'o' => '0',
        's' => '5',
        't' => '7'
    }
    @@re = Regexp.union(@@map.keys)

    def self.speak(str)
        str.gsub(@@re, @@map)
    end
end

puts Leet.speak('leet')
# l337
```

Adjust `@@map` as needed and away you go.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Yeah, [`Regexp.union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union) is super-handy, way better than trying to escape and concatenate strings together to dynamically build regexes. I think I learned about it from [Phrogz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz).

Comment: thsnka for your answer too, a bit too advanced for me maybe :D